# HOW TO FIX java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\profilepics\default.jpg

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, glassfish

Im having an error in my glassfish server. Saying that my folder/file does not exist. I copied and paste the path stated here and the image is there. I'm displaying an image from here to my JSP.

```
    [2017-10-05T20:39:38.389+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] 
    [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] 
    [timeMillis: 1507207178389] [levelValue: 900] [[
    StandardWrapperValve[spring]: Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw 
    exception
    java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Adminitrator-
    IT\Desktop\default.jpg
    at 
    sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at 
    sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at 
    sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at 
sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:317)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:363)
    at 
java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:380)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:108)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:2895)
    at com.project.controller.UploadController.readImage(UploadController.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

I'm definitely a beginner. I'm using Spring and glassfish 4. Here is my code in my Controller,

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getavatar/{value}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public void readImage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@PathVariable String value)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            //int cifid = authenticationFacade.getSessionData().getCifid(); 

            ServletContext sc = request.getServletContext();



            File image = new File(com.aimglobalinc.constants.AimConstants.AVATAR_FOLDER + value + "_avatar.jpg");

            if(!image.exists()){
                image = new File(com.aimglobalinc.constants.AimConstants.AVATAR_FOLDER + "default.jpg");
            } 

            String contentType = sc.getMimeType(image.getName());
            response.reset();
            response.setContentType(contentType);
            response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(image.length()));
            Files.copy(image.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
        }
```

Comment: I know this might seem obvious, but have you in fact confirmed that the file actually does exist?

Comment: Yes sir the file exist . it is in that path. and i tried to copy the path that is stated in this error. and put it in file explorer. the image showed up

Comment: Which is line 96 in your UploadController? edit: 96 not 108

Comment: "Files.copy(image.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());" This is line 96 sir, I do not know whats wrong here. I debug my webapp in eclipse everything is fine but when i deploy it to glassfish. this error comes up.

Comment: Are you deploying to Glassfish on your local machine or a remote server?

Comment: I have a glassfish in my pc. I deployed it also there and its working smoothly. But when i deployed it in the remote server this error occurred.

Comment: So the file exists on your local machine, but does it exist on the remote server?

Comment: No Sir alpha. I have also the file in my remote server. Is there something i can do with line 96?

Comment: So the file is also on your remote servers desktop then yes? What about the user for the remote server, is it the same username of `Adminitrator-
    IT`?

Comment: What is the value of com.aimglobalinc.constants.AimConstants.AVATAR_FOLDER ?

Comment: I'm also just noticing the path in the title of your question is different than the path in the error

Comment: Thats the path where the image is located from the server. At first it was C:profilepicture\default.jpg that time it also giving the same error message Then i have read an article that it must be in desktop.  and thats the reason why is it in that path. 
The value of the AVATAR_FOLDER now  in my server is C:profilepics\default.jpg and still gives the same error

Comment: I already updated it here in my server still the same error.. its also pointing on line 96.

Comment: Does it open the image if you perform "windows + r" and write on the run dialog box:
C:\Users\Adminitrator-IT\Desktop\default.jpg?

Comment: No Sir. Additional information sir . our server doesnt have a photo viewer . Does this do something else with this ?